# Rails 4: using MiniTest AND Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

Is it possible and does anyone have experience using minitest and rspec?
I'm just wondering if it's possible to slowly migrate from one to the other and have both get along in the mean time.

I tried setting up some minitest tests in an rspec project and it's just failing silently at this point. I've even removed the rspec-rails gem but still

```
rake test my/test/file.rb
```

just silently returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just revisited this and it seems like Rspec and Minitest work fine together "out of the box" without needing minitest-rails.

I'm not however using minitest/spec so I don't know about how that would integrate.

My issue was that the project in question was explicitly setting up individual railties in config/application.rb just to exclude "rails/test_unit/railtie" which is great if you just want rspec.

I put it back to the default

```
require 'rails/all'
```

and now both rspec specs run with

```
rake spec
```

and minitest tests run with

```
rake test
```

I wanted both to run buy default with just

```
rake
```

So I put this in my Rakefile

```
Rake::Task["default"].clear if Rake::Task.task_defined?("default")
task :default do
  puts "Starting specs"
  system('bundle exec rake spec')

  puts "Starting Minitest tests"
  system('bundle exec rake test')
end
```

Comment: ouch.  How about
"task default: [:spec, :test]"

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t| 
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
end

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t| 
  t.pattern = Dir.glob('spec/**/*_spec.rb')
  # t.rspec_opts = '--format documentation'
end

task default: [:test, :spec]
```

Comment: Thanks! The rspec rake task bit is exactly what I was missing. In my case, I also needed to set `require: false` on rspec-rails in my Gemfile (because it conflicts with minitest).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do that. Minitest is part of the standard library, so there should not be any conflicts.

If you want `rake test` to execute minitest, you will have to configure rails to use it. This might be useful for doing it: https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails

Otherwise you could just execute a test directly `ruby -Itest test/unit/whatever_test.rb`